# JTable Edit Panel

Tags: html, css, jquery-jtable

I have incorporated the JTable Plugin which I like very much and works fine.

The only "issue" I have is that I would like to edit the Edit Record Panel. When I say by editing, I am meaning that I would like to insert a new text input. Is this possible?

[image: Screenshot Edit Panel]

For example in the image above, I would like to enter the following inputs:

1. Old Password
2. New Password
3. Confirm Password

Answer (score 0):

Add these 3 fields to your jTable and set 'list' to false and 'edit to true.

```
fields: {
            OldPassword: {
                title: 'Old Password',
                list: false,
                edit: true
            },
            NewPassword: {
                title: 'New Password',
                list: false,
                edit: true
            },
            ConfirmPassword: {
                title: 'Confirm Password',
                list: false,
                edit: true
            }
```

Don't forget to add these 3 properties to your model.
You may also want to validate the passwords. I think you can add the logic by adding this event to your table :

```
formSubmitting: function (event, data) {
            //Compare passwords and validate logic    

            return data.form.validationEngine('validate');
        }
```